# LinkedIn title change ettiquette

Tags: job-change, title, social-media

When you accept a new job, when do you change your "current" position on LinkedIn and other social networks? Do you wait until you've officially started? As soon as you put in notice?

Just curious as to what the masses do. Even though I've got another week to go, I'm starting to clear my personal belongings out of my office, and that made me start thinking about this sort of thing.

Comment: SOP is to wait until you actually start the job on the off-chance that the offer falls through. That said, this is probably largely a matter of opinion as well as relatively meaningless.

Comment: I'm currently in this state and you **cannot** (LinkedIn doesn't allow it) update your profile to add a new position, because you cannot use a starting date that is in the future. You also cannot leave the date empty.

Comment: "Do you wait until you've officially started?". Yes. At least then, if not longer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My attitude is simple: It depends on the job, your desire to let others know about it and your comfort level/assurance you have a future at a job.

In my personal experience, I have only updated LinkedIn and Facebook info at least 1-2 months *after* I have left a position and started a new one; sometimes even 3 months after. Why? Simple: Sometimes your desire to leave a company might result in the company coming back at you a few weeks later asking you to stay onboard. Or a new position might seem fine at first, but after a few months you want out; do you want that odd “less than a year” blip on your job history?

So if you are unsure about this, then you should follow the standard concept/timeframe of an employment probation period. In many countries you might start a job on one date, but only after 3 months will you be qualified for benefits and other “perks” of the job. This probation period is often done as a way of admitting, “You know what? Why should we spend time and resources ramping someone into a pension plan if they might leave in 1-2 months for something else?” So the 3 month probation period can be seen as a buffer between what your job expectations are versus what the reality is.

And with that in mind, maybe it would be best to only update your social media details after that 3 month point has been reached?

Answer (score 6):

I think that there are two parts to this question.

First, when you are leaving one position, you need to update your profiles to reflect that you are no longer in this position. I think that this can safely be done as soon as you give your notice, but the better option would be to wait until you have officially left your position, turned in your work resources, and have left the workplace for the very last time. At this same point in time, you can update the description for this position to accurately reflect your job duties, responsibilities, and achievements.

The next step is to add your new position to your profile. Here, you should wait to make sure that you will be staying at this position for a length of time. If you have a probationary period (since usually, probationary periods work both ways), wait until the end of the probationary period. If you don't have a probationary period or you have a long probationary period, wait at least 2-4 weeks to make sure that this is a position that you will be at. This also gives you a chance to fully understand what work you will doing and writing something somewhat meaningful for the details of the position.

Something that you didn't mention: connecting to your new colleagues. If your new colleagues request to connect with you, you can accept or decline at your will. However, I would not recommend sending out requests to connect of your own until you've added the new position to your profile.

Answer (score 1):

> Do you wait until you've officially started? As soon as you put in
>   notice?

If you've left the job(and office) in Jan '16, then that should be the end-month for your current job on LinkedIn (update it as soon as you leave the job).

Then, the month you'd be actually starting at your new job should be the starting date for that job on LinkedIn, and not earlier. (That's the general convention followed.)